# Multi Level URL in Umbraco for Inner Pages

Tags: umbraco

I am using UmbracoCMS for one of the my project. I want to create 3 pages as following hierarchy.

- About US

  - Key People

    - Matt Krikman

AboutUS is parent node for KeyPeople and Profile Page is child of KeyPeople.
[image]

So I am expecting following url for each page
**About US -> www.mydomain.com/aboutus

KeyPeople -> www.mydomain.com/aboutus/KeyPeople

PeopleProfile -> www.mydomain.com/aboutus/KeyPeople/RyanPinkard**

But When I check for KeyPeople and RyanPinkard, I am getting following URL in backoffice:[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default Umbraco does not include top level nodes in the URL because it expects them to be the root of your website.  To include them in the URL go to your web config and update the `umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath` app setting:

`<add key="umbracoHideTopLevelNodeFromPath" value="false" />`

Alternatively you could move **Contact** and **AboutUs** so that they sit beneath **Home**. This would give you the expected page URLs.